# Flat object to nested objects in Automapper

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper-2

I use Automapper all the time, and for some reason the issue is escaping me. Below is an example of the code I'm using (names have been changed.)

**Problem**
All objects are mapped but the **Keys** object.

**Code**
I have a flat object coming from a WCF service.

```
public class FlatDTO
{
public string Key1 {get;set;}
public string Key2 {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

This is the structure for my Business Object:

```
public class BaseModel
{
public Datetime Date{get;set;}
}

public class Keys
{
public string Key1 {get;set;}
public string Key2 {get;set;}
}

public class Summary : BaseModel
{
public Keys List {get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}

public Summary ()
{
List = new Keys();
}
}
```

Below is my profile for Automapper (the init of the profile is done in the global.aspx page)

```
internal class MapDTO : Profile
{
protected override void configure()
{
  Mapper.CreateMap<FlatDTO,BaseModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.CreateMap<FlatDTO,Role>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.CreateMap<FlatDTO,Summary>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

}

Help with this 'simple' issue would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper expression must resolve to top-level member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633021/automapper-expression-must-resolve-to-top-level-member)