# Automapper expression must resolve to top-level member

Tags: automapper, .net, automapper-2

I am using automapper to map source and destination objects. While I map them I get the below error.

> Expression must resolve to top-level member. Parameter name: lambdaExpression

I am not able resolve the issue.

My source and destination objects are:

```
public partial class Source
{
        private Car[] cars;

        public Car[] Cars
        {
            get { return this.cars; }
            set { this.cars = value; }
        }
}

public partial class Destination
{
        private OutputData output;

        public OutputData Output
        {            
            get {  return this.output; }
            set {  this.output= value; }
        }
}

public class OutputData
{
        private List<Cars> cars;

        public Car[] Cars
        {
            get { return this.cars; }
            set { this.cars = value; }
        }
}
```

I have to map `Source.Cars` with `Destination.OutputData.Cars` object. Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Could you add automapper configuration?

Comment: I tried to add the configuration, it throws error while running the configurations. My configuration looks as below                                              Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember( dest => dest.OutputData.Cars, input => input.MapFrom(i => i.Cars));                                                                                                                                                                                          Expression 'dest => dest.OutputData.Cars' must resolve to top-level member.
Parameter name: lambdaExpression

Comment: This worked for me:
`Mapper.CreateMap<Destination, Source>().ForMember(x => x.Cars, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.OutputData.Cars)).ReverseMap();`
(also posted in an answer below)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554788/deep-level-mapping-using-automapper related

Answer (score 51):

You are using :

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
 .ForMember( dest => dest.OutputData.Cars, 
             input => input.MapFrom(i => i.Cars));
```

This won't work because you are using 2 level in the dest lambda.

With Automapper, you can only map to 1 level. To fix the problem you need to use a single level :

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
 .ForMember( dest => dest.OutputData, 
             input => input.MapFrom(i => new OutputData{Cars=i.Cars}));
```

This way, you can set your cars to the destination.

Comment: Also used this solution for mapping between objects where the source had `string somethingKey` and `string somethingValue`, and the destination had `object something { string Key, string Value }`

Comment: Greate Answer!!

Answer (score 18):

You can do it that way:

```
// First: create mapping for the subtypes
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, OutputData>();

// Then: create the main mapping
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().
    // chose the destination-property and map the source itself
    ForMember(dest => dest.Output, x => x.MapFrom(src => src));
```

That's my way to do that ;-)

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: Works perfect when you want map IDataRecord to complex DTO.

Comment: A much more elegant way, compared to the most voted answer, which could lead to some very convoluted syntax.

Answer (score 17):

1. Define mapping between `Source` and `OutputData`.

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Source, OutputData>();
   ```
2. Update your configuration to map `Destination.Output` with `OutputData`.

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember( dest => dest.Output, input => 
       input.MapFrom(s=>Mapper.Map<Source, OutputData>(s)));
   ```

Comment: I have field in the OutputData which has some default value. I don't have a mapping for this field in the source. So I didn't map it. After mapping is done, my default value is set to null value on the destination. How to avoid it setting to a null value.

Answer (score 7):

ForPath works for this exact scenario.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Destination, Source>().ForPath(dst => dst.OutputData.Cars, e => e.MapFrom(src => src.Cars));
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Destination, Source>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Cars, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.OutputData.Cars))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer given by allrameest on this question should help: [AutoMapper - Deep level mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554788/automapper-deep-level-mapping)

This is what you need:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OutputData, opt => opt.MapFrom(i => i));
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, OutputData>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Cars, opt => opt.MapFrom(i => i.Cars));
```

When using the mapper, use:

```
var destinationObj = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(sourceObj)
```

where destinationObj is an instance of Destination and sourceObj is an instance of Source.

NOTE: You should try to move away from using Mapper.CreateMap at this point, it is obsolete and will be unsupported soon.